# Cannot change file name on desktop

Tags: permissions, files

I cannot change the name of a file/directory on the desktop through right click on the icon. The name becomes selected, but I cannot type in it. This has also happened in the past with some versions of Ubuntu. Is this a bug, or am I not doing it correctly?

Comment: I have the similar issue, but it the problem was not only on the desktop, but in every file-manager window. After Reboot - everything got back to normal. I did not find other ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To change the name on Ubuntu (unlike OS X) you need to right-click and then choose 'rename'.  If you then cannot type to change the name, that's a bug.  As a workaround you could try then left-clicking on the name to see if that puts focus in the right place.

It could be that you're hitting the problem described in [gnome bug 646900](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646900), which is fixed upstream and should be fixed in Ubuntu in a bit.  That bug reports suggests some workarounds.

If that doesn't sound like your bug, I suggest you report it by running in the Terminal:

```
apport-bug nautilus
```

Comment: That is what I have been doing. It seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using focus-follows-mouse on Unity? If yes, you can only rename the desktop icons by if there are no applictions open on the desktop. It's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/889145