# Cannot rename .theme file in Drupal 8 installation

Tags: permissions, files

I don't know if this is an Ubuntu question or a Drupal question but since it SEEMS OS-related I'll ask it here. Sorry if that's a mistake. Here's my question:

**Summary of problem:**

I've added a bootstrap sub-theme to my new Drupal 8 site and am in the process of changing the name of all the files to reflect my sub-themes name. I was able to change the .info.yml and libraries.yml files just fine but I get an error whenever I try to change the THEMENAME.theme file to match my sub-theme name. I tried this with multiple installations of Drupal 8.

**Current permissions:**

I have already given myself full permissions over the site directory to do whatever I want, using the following: `sudo chmod ugo+wrx /var/www/drupal/ -Rf`

I've also given the apache user ownership over the site directory, like so: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/sitename/*`

**This is the error I get:**

Sorry, could not rename “THEMENAME.theme” to “new-subtheme-name.theme”: Unable to rename desktop file.

Thoughts on what might be going on here?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/65343/cannot-change-file-name-on-desktop

Comment: Thanks but restarting doesn't help and I've even re-installed the operating system and it still causes this problem and only on THIS file. I have no problems renaming other files on my OS, including other files in this same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. As a workaround I created `new-subtheme-name.theme`, copied code from `THEMENAME.theme` over to the new file and deleted `THEMENAME.theme`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It would still be good to know the reason for not being able to edit the original file though.